# Cloud9 in Android App

Tags: android, webserver, cloud9-ide

I am building an Android App for my college, which need to compile different type of programming languages. Can I somehow use the **Cloud9** IDE as a compiler in my App ? please guide me.

**expected working:** App will send the program to the cloud9 and compiles and returns output/errors or prompts for Input (if any).

**Or**

Is there any other way I could make this feature work with the App.